# How can I have different margins in Libre Office Writer?

Tags: printing, libreoffice, libreoffice-writer, margins, duplex

I need to write a document that will be printed front/back on multiple sheets that are then to be stapled together.

I need to leave different margins depending if the page is even or odd, for one I need wider margin right for another on the left. Is it possible to achieve this?

What would be the best practice in this case?

Answer (score 5):

#### I need to leave different margins depending if the page is even or odd

You should use a "Mirrored" page layout:

> **Mirrored**
>
> The current page style shows both odd and even pages with inner and
>   outer margins as specified. Use this layout if you want to bind the
>   printed pages like a book.
>
> Enter the binding space as the "Inner"
>   margin.

Source [Page Layout](https://help.libreoffice.org/Common/Page#Page_Layout)

1. Menu > "Format" > "Page...".
2. Select "Page" tab.
3. Select "Mirrored" in "Page layout"
4. Set "Inner" and "Outer" as appropriate.
5. Click "OK"

   [image]

Comment: thank you! Is it also possible to selectively set for each page on what side it should have the wider margin?

Comment: @Ritardi.Net Possibly. I think you would need multiple sections for that. I've never tried it.

Comment: Just create different page styles for your liking, apply to the pages you want to set. Note, that every time you set a page style the following style change to what is defined on `Organizer` tab - so just do it from top to bottom.